# SQL query running slowly due to calling main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am trying to speed up a query but I am unable to see away past how the query I need to do, the old query was using functions which are slow so I have replaced them which does speed the query up but when the full query is put together it is no faster. The problem is that I have to call my main table for each sub query which there are 10. below is part of the query as the full thing is a bit long should give you an idea of what the problem is.

Thanks a lot!

Thomas

New Code -

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(dd, - DATEPART(dd, msValidFrom) + 1, msValidFrom) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS MemMonth,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT me_csID) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.tblMembershipStatus 
    WHERE (ms_memID IN (@memID)) 
        AND (msDurationType IN (@memType)) 
        AND (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(dd, - DATEPART(dd, MainMonth.msValidFrom) + 1, MainMonth.msValidFrom) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)) 
        BETWEEN CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(dd, - DATEPART(dd, msValidFrom) + 1, msValidFrom) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) 
        AND CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(dd, - DATEPART(dd, msValidUntil) + 1, msValidUntil) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)) AS active
FROM tblMembershipStatus AS MainMonth
WHERE (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(dd, - DATEPART(dd, msValidFrom) + 1, msValidFrom) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) 
GROUP BY msValidFrom
ORDER BY MemMonth
```

Same code but how it did look -

```
SELECT Purple7Master.dbo.fnc_GetMonthStart(msValidFrom) AS [MemMonth],
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT me_csID) AS Expr1
    FROM dbo.tblMembershipStatus
    WHERE (ms_memID IN (@memID)) 
        AND (msDurationType IN (@memType)) 
        AND (Purple7Master.dbo.fnc_GetMonthStart(MainMonth.msValidFrom) 
        BETWEEN Purple7Master.dbo.fnc_GetMonthStart(msValidFrom) 
        AND Purple7Master.dbo.fnc_GetMonthStart(msValidUntil))) AS [active]     
FROM tblMembershipStatus AS MainMonth
WHERE (Purple7Master.dbo.fnc_GetMonthStart(msValidFrom) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
GROUP BY Purple7Master.dbo.fnc_GetMonthStart(msValidFrom)
ORDER BY MemMonth
```

Comment: Where's your execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of work to do here this is just a partial answer to you start with.

```
WHERE (CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(dd, - DATEPART(dd, msValidFrom) + 1, msValidFrom) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```

first this is very inefficient. You are handling every row from table and forcing a full table scan.

You must change it to something like

```
WHERE msValidFrom between @calculated_StartDate and @calculated_endDate
```

and creating a index over msValidFrom ill speed up things.

you can also do some calc just before that select:

```
declare @Calculated_date datetime
SET @calcualted_date = cast(floor( ......... @no_calculated_date.....))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to rephrase what you have, and what APPEARS to be completely wasteful conversions killing your query.  You want a count of members for each month basis between a given time period @StartDate, @EndDate for a specific member ID @memID and duration of membership @memType

Showing the table structures, and sample data will help, but lets look at what your conversions are doing and why it may be overkill.

```
CAST( FLOOR( CAST( DATEADD(dd, - DATEPART(dd, msValidFrom) + 1, msValidFrom) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS MemMonth,
```

Looking at the inner-most...

```
DatePart(dd, msValidFrom) returns the DAY a member is valid from ex: 12th of the month
DateAdd( dd, -DatePart(dd, msValidFrom) +1, msValidFrom ) is basically saying 
Take Dec 12, subtract 12 days to get to last day of November 30, then add 1 to bring it 
back to the first day of December, so you have the month 12 (December)
```

Why not just use

```
DatePart( mm, msValidFrom ) to give you 12 (December).
```

SQL handles that for any of the date/time components.

Just that in itself will simplify your headache.

To help, I would have an index on your tblMembershipStatus ON

```
( ms_memID, msDurationType, msValidFrom )
```

Now, your OUTER WHERE clause. You are doing the same thing there, and if there is an index on the date.  I would just have your @StartDate and @EndDate in a proper format of begin/end of month respectively

The start Date would be something like

```
@StartDate = '2013-11-01'  (which defaults to 12:00:00 AM)
@EndDate = '2013-12-01'  (which also defaults to 12:00:00 AM)
```

Then, your WHERE clause could be

```
WHERE 
      ms_memID in @memID
  AND msDurationType in @memType
  AND msValidFrom >= @StartDate 
  AND msValidFrom < @EndDate  (notice not <= end date which would include Dec 1)
```

FINALLY your group by.  You have it by the msValidFrom, but there are no aggregations being done (sum, min, max, avg) as you are just doing DISTINCT, and if for a given month you have people signing up on all different days of a month FOR membership, you will get EACH day with a count, but a very hard way about it.  I would suggest doing something along the lines of

```
SELECT 
      datepart( yyyy, MS.msValidFrom ) memberYear,
      datepart( mm, MS.msValidFrom ) memberMonth,
      COUNT(*) as ActiveMembers
   from
      dbo.tblMembershipStatus MS
   WHERE 
          MS.ms_memID = @memID
      AND MS.msDurationType = @memType
      AND MS.msValidFrom >= @StartDate
      AND MS.msValidUntil < @EndDate
   group by
      datepart( yyyy, MS.msValidFrom ),
      datepart( mm, MS.msValidFrom )
```

But again, this is without seeing actual table structures, sample data, nor your expected desires results (suggesting you update your original post.  Don't use tabs for alignment, but spaces, then Ctrl+K to block format it).